# Optimize sub query using stddev for forex data history

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, parameter-passing, where-clause

I am trying to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT idnum AS ID, 
   (SELECT stddev(close) 
    from hist.eurusd1 
    where idnum between ID-7 AND ID) AS Sdev 
FROM hist.eurusd1 
where idnum between 1001 and 2000;
```

It is taking about **1800 secs** for only 1000 rows and I have about 1 million rows to process.

A simple `STDDEV` query executes much more faster:

```
SELECT stddev(close)
from hist.eurusd1
where idnum between 1003 AND 1010;
```

like 0.047 sec for the first time for the fetch part, so 1000 queries would be like 47 secs instead of 1800 secs.

I think that something in the sub-query is making the whole first query slower, but don't know how to optimize it.

Comment: apples to oranges comparision `where idnum between 1003 AND 1010; ` and `where idnum between 1001 and 2000;`

Comment: Check out MariaDB's "windowing functions" in 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't an answer, because I can't explain why the given subquery is so slow.
But I did figure out how to calculate the million rows in about 30 seconds, so I wanted to post the code:

```
SELECT a.idnum as id, stddev(b.close)
from eurusd1 as a
JOIN (
   select idnum+7 as ix, close from eurusd1
   UNION ALL
   select idnum+6 as ix, close from eurusd1
   UNION ALL
   select idnum+5 as ix, close from eurusd1
   UNION ALL
   select idnum+4 as ix, close from eurusd1
   UNION ALL
   select idnum+3 as ix, close from eurusd1
   UNION ALL
   select idnum+2 as ix, close from eurusd1
   UNION ALL
   select idnum+1 as ix, close from eurusd1
   UNION ALL
   select idnum as ix, close from eurusd1
    ) as b on a.idnum = b.ix
group by a.idnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Can get close in with [*MariaDB 10.2 Window functions*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-frames/) .

I don't see STD, but AVG would go something like:

```
AVG(close) OVER(ORDER BY idnum
                RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING
                          AND CURRENT ROW)
     AS MovingAvg
```